# Only allow a certain range of numbers to be inputted into an input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to set an input field that should accept only numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, it should only accept single digits

```
                   <input
                      type="number"
                      step="1" // Set step to "1" to allow only single-digit numbers
                      min="1"
                       max="10"
                      value={skill.editedRating || skill.rating} 
                      onChange={(e) => handleRatingChange(e, skill.skillId)}
                      onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
                    />

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
const input = event.target;
const inputValue = input.value;

// Check if the input value contains more than one digit
if (inputValue.length > 1) {
  // Clear the input field and set it to the last digit entered
  input.value = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length - 1);
}
};




  const handleRatingChange = (event, Id) => {  
  const arr = skills.filter((element) => {
  if (element.skillId == Id) {
    element.rating = event.target.value;
  }
  return element;
  });
setSkills(arr);
 };
```

this is my code now its accepting 2 digits instead of one.

Comment: `it should only accept single digits` ... er, but `10` is 2 digits.

Comment: Use a select not an input

Comment: i mean 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 any of these at a time

Answer (score 1):

You could check your min and max value. Whenever it exceeds one of these, replace the value with the correct value:

```js
function restrictInputRange(input) {
    const min = parseFloat(input.min);
    const max = parseFloat(input.max);
    const value = parseFloat(input.value);

    // Not a number? Empty input
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      input.value = ''
      return
    }
    
    // Now we know it's a number,
    // Check if it exceeds a limit
    if (value < min) {
        input.value = min;
    } else if (value > max) {
        input.value = max;
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="numberInput">Enter a number between 1 and 10:</label>
<input type="number" id="numberInput" min="1" max="10" oninput="restrictInputRange(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the input event `onKeyDown` to `onInput`, just because without this, the event doesn't pick up the current changes made.

You might also need to modify your `handleKeyDown` function slightly thus:

```js
  // It's worth renaming this function to handleInput
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    const input = event.target;
    let inputValue = input.value;

    // Check if the input value is greater than 10 or starts with a zero
    if (inputValue > 10 || inputValue.toString().startsWith("0")) {
      // Clear the input field and set it to the last digit entered
      input.value = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length - 1);
    }
  };
```